# file_put_contents() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, laravel, path, filesystems

I upload my Laravel on a subfolder on an existing site and having that issue.

[image]

I found the solution on google but everywhere talks about permission denied or something, how do I resolve it? guide me, please.

```
file_put_contents() has been disabled for security reasons

  public function replace($path, $content)
     {
         // If the path already exists and is a symlink, get the real v
```

path...
clearstatcache(true, $path);

```
         $path = realpath($path) ?: $path;

         $tempPath = tempnam(dirname($path), basename($path));

         // Fix permissions of tempPath because `tempnam()` creates it with permissions set to 0600...
         chmod($tempPath, 777 - umask());

         file_put_contents($tempPath, $content);

         rename($tempPath, $path);
     }
```

Comment: I think you have to ask your hosting support.

Comment: Get a better hosting provider.

Comment: if i contact them and ask for permission, than this error will be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your php.ini file, and look for the `disable-functions` directive. If you see `file_put_contents` listed there, then that is the cause of the error.

Remove `file_put_contents` from this setting, and restart your php service.

See [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) reference in the PHP Manual

Comment: I strongly suspect OP is on shared hosting and has no access to the `php.ini`. That's about the only situation you'd find `file_get_contents` disabled by default.

Comment: i need some other help if i upload a file in subfolder with formate html or simple php file that's working preety nice but laravel project is not working error comes "file_put_contents() has been disabled for security reasons" why?

Comment: @عمررشید Do you have access to edit `php.ini`? If you do not have access, then you need to contact your webhost.

Comment: there is no php.ini file exist on server.....error solved i change my hosting service.